# typehint the builtin map to provide parallel alternatives

Tags: python, functional-programming, type-hinting

I'm trying to define alternatives to the builtin `map` function in python to provide multi threading and multiprocessing maps. Here is the protocol I have defined, based on the signature of the builtin `map`:

```py
class Map(Protocol):
    def __call__(
        self, func: Callable[..., T], *iterables: Iterable[Any]
    ) -> Iterable[T]:
        ...
```

However when i just want to use the built in map i get a compile time typehint error:

```py
def some_function(mapper: Map=map):
    pass
```

Gives the following warning:
Expression of type "type[map[Unknown]]" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "Map"
No overloaded function matches type "(func: (...) -> T@**call**, *iterables: Iterable[Any]) -> Iterable[T@**call**]"

The code runs fine, but I want the type hints to be correct as well. how should I fix this?

I have tried to make it work the other way around as well:

```py
def some_function(mapper: type[map]=map): # totally fine :)
    pass

# MultiProcessingMap is an instance that conforms to the Map protocol
some_function(mapper=MultiProcessingMap(5)) # compile time error, runtime fine
```

Argument of type "MultiProcessingMap" cannot be assigned to parameter "mapper" of type "type[map[Unknown]]" in function "some_function"
Type "MultiProcessingMap" cannot be assigned to type "type[map[Unknown]]"

Bonus question: How can extend the type hinting of Map to cover the types of the arguments of `func` as well?